# Is it okay to use the same password more than once for AES?

Tags: security, aes

I know that certain ciphers (like substitution ciphers) can be broken if a password is used to encrypt 2 or more messages. Is this the case with AES?

Comment: Try posting in http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/reusing-keys-with-aes-cbc

Comment: You're looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack - AES is generally immune to it.

Comment: @oakad You mean "currently has no known exploitable weakness" to a related key attack. Still, if security is a concern, I would recommend a forward secrecy key exchange step be added (unless you want to implement the NSA certificate extensions).

Comment: "Currently has no known exploitable weakness" can be assumed by default for anything crypto related. :)

Comment: @oakad given the OPs level of demonstrated understanding, I thought I'd throw that in :P